# Python version 2.4.4 in which it unlocks some features after reading a license file from the path "C:/filename "

Tags: python, windows-7, operating-system, pycrypto, sys

I had an application build with the Python version `2.4.4`. It unlocks some features after reading a license file from the path "C:/filename ".

But it is not working while trying on the other machine with `Win-7 OS`, while working on other machines successfully.

Note: Out of 10 machines 1 machine is facing with this problem.

The file which it is directed to read is just a decrypted file created using the volume number of the O.S using py-crypto.

Can anyone suggest me to sort this out?

Comment: Well. bad luck. Please provide additional info, how it fails, backtrace, what code you use to read that file...

Comment: No Error message on the screen It just shows found on console window if found, if not it shows not found.

Comment: open (path) to read the file.

Comment: Is this recent error! which was working fine before! if yes then there are some updates installed in Windows 7 which have made python non working!! :(

Comment: You mean that when, win-7 updates this makes python non working is it so?

Comment: But, i am working on my machine on which the code is developed its working fine....

Comment: if so,it is working fine on my machine on which the application is compiled and build making the changes in the code.if i remove the updates from the machine where the license file error is occurring,Does it work ?

Comment: its not possible to remove the installed updates,Is there any way to resolve this issue?